# django @login_required decorator for a last_name, only users with last_name == 'kitchen' entry

Tags: django, django-views

Is there a decorator in django similar to @login_required that also tests if the user has lastname == kitchen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator to create any custom user check decorator

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def lastname_kitchen_check(user):
    return user.lastname == 'kitchen'

@user_passes_test(lastname_kitchen_check)
def view(request):
    ...
```